# C++ Binary search algorithm to work like lower_bound

Tags: c++, search, binary, lower-bound

I do have another question following my previous -

I am creating a version of `lower_bound` with something like binary search. With the `BinarySearch` function I find a place where to insert the new item and with the for cycle I do move the rest of the array and insert the right item so I can insert it to the right position.

But the following `BinarySearch` function does not work properly.

**Can anyone see why?**

```
bool CReg::AddCar ( const char *name){
    CArr * tmp = new CArr(name); // an item I am going to insert
    int pos = BinarySearch(name,0,len); //len = number of items in array
    checkLen(); // whether I do have enough space to move the array right
    if (length!=0)
        for (int i = m_len; i>=pos; i-- )
            Arr[i+1] = spzArr[i];
    Arr[pos] = tmp;
    length++;
    checkLen();
    return true;
}

int BinarySearch(const char * name, int firstindex, int lastindex) {
    if (lenght == 0) return 0; //number of items in array
    if (firstindex == lastindex) return lastindex;
    int tmp = lastindex - firstindex;
    int pos = firstindex + tmp / 2; //position the new item should go to
    if (tmp % 2)++pos;
    if (lastindex == pos || firstindex == pos) return pos;
    if (strcmp(name, Arr[pos]) < 0) return BinarySearch(name, firstindex, pos - 1);
    if (strcmp(name, Arr[pos]) > 0) return BinarySearch(name, pos + 1, lastindex);
    return pos;
    }
```

Comment: @Jarod42 - that was a typo, srry

Comment: @erolyeniaras it does not sort 10 items properly

Comment: @Jesse_Pinkman `it does not sort 10 items properly`  That's like calling a mechanic on the phone and just saying "my car doesn't work".    Please elaborate as to what you mean by "properly"?  What debugging have you done?  Where does the code take the wrong path, a variable is set incorrectly, etc.?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie for when you add items in this order (letters - to have it easy) : C, B, A, F, D, E, G, H ,I - and i want them to be sorted alphabetically it outputs D, A, B ,F, C ,E H, I - it moves the items in a bad way

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have added more of the code - this is everything if is related to - the checkLen function resizes the array if length+1 = size

Comment: @Jesse_Pinkman `CArr * tmp = new CArr(name); `  You don't use `tmp` anywhere in your function.  Maybe you should post the full code, along with the `main` program you're with.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that was another typo, but I have rewritten the code and it works - thanks for your time !

Comment: @Jesse_Pinkman  I am glad you have an answer to your question, but [THIS IS IMPORTANT] now you need to make the answer available on StackOverflow!  The purpose of stack overflow is not to just fix your problem (although that's a pleasant side effect.) The purpose is to create a set of questions and answers that will be useful to many programmers over time.    Yes it is OK to answer your own question--in fact you will get reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed version of `BinarySearch`

```
int BinarySearch(const char* name, int firstindex, int lastindex)
{
    if (firstindex == lastindex) return lastindex;
    int dist = lastindex - firstindex;
    int mid = firstindex + dist / 2; //position the new item should go to
    if (strcmp(name, Arr[mid]) < 0) return BinarySearch(name, firstindex, mid);
    if (strcmp(name, Arr[mid]) > 0) return BinarySearch(name, mid + 1, lastindex);
    return mid;
}
```

But you may directly use `std::lower_bound`:

```
// Assuming std::vector<std::string> Arr;

void CReg::AddCar(const std::string& name)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(Arr.begin(), Arr.end(), name);
    Arr.insert(it, name);
}
```